# jfreechart setBackgroundpaint not working

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to merge multiple graphs to create a single chart. The individual graphs have White background but somehow my merged chart end up getting gray background despite using setBackgroundpaint api.

```
public static String mergeXYGraphs(List<XYPlot> plots, String title, boolean legend, int width, int height) throws IOException
{
    if(plots != null && !plots.isEmpty())
    {
        XYPlot base = plots.get(0);
        for(int i = 1; i< plots.size(); i++)
        {
            base.setDataset(i, plots.get(i).getDataset());
            base.setRenderer(i, plots.get(i).getRenderer());
        }
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(title, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, base, legend);
        setDateAxis(base);
        chart.getXYPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        return saveImageFile(chart, "merged", "charts", width, height);
    }
    return "";
}


private static void setDateAxis(XYPlot plot)
{
    DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis();
    domainAxis.setAutoTickUnitSelection(true);
    domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM"));
    plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
}
```

PS : base.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE); doesn't work either

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that we have to set colors on different levels on jfreechart to control the colors of different parts.

In the image above the background color of the panel is white but the background color of the chart isn't. So, I had to use:

```
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
```